# Design Pattern, adding data to a class (3rd party) without modifying it

Tags: c++, design-patterns

When I have to extend the behaviour of a class without modifying it, I often use the design pattern [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). It adds member-like functions without modifying the core of the class it works with.

More or less in the same way, I need to extend a third party class, but mostly with data, not behaviour.

In such cases, I often use a std::map matching the a key `MyClass*` with a value `MyClassExtender`. MyClassExtender contains all the additionnal information.

While doing that, I happened to wonder if there are other ways of doing that, maybe more common or more 'best-practice". Should I call this additive class an Extender ? 
Is there a name for such a pattern...

Nota Bene: I could have simply aggregated the MyClass* and MyClassExtender in a new class, but I need to access MyClassExtender given a MyClass* really often, so the st::map is really convinient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just subclass the class? Inheritance is the way to extend classes, whether with behavior or state. Unless you just want to associate instances of the class with other data, in which case it's not extending at all, and a std::map is the right answer.

Comment: *Inheritance is the way to extend classes, whether with behavior or state.* => **No!!** Inheritance is *overused* because it seems so convenient, but most of the time **Composition** should be used instead. In this particular case, this might be a solution, but your justification is wrong: a decision to inherit is never trivial.

Comment: @Matthieu m. I was hoping that someonelse than me would say it :-) "Prefer aggregation over inheritance".

Answer (score 1):

So - create your MyClass object with in the struct with your extension objects:

```
struct MyClassEx {
  MyClassExtension extension;
  MyClass object;
};
```

To make it more robustness for different types - use templates from the example: http://ideone.com/mmfK83

The solution below is inspired by `std::shared_ptr/std::make_shared`:

```
template <typename Type>
struct LinkExtension;

template <typename Type>
struct TypeEx {
    using Extension = typename LinkExtension<Type>::Type;

    alignas(Type) uint8_t objectData[sizeof(Type)];
    alignas(Extension) uint8_t extensionData[sizeof(Extension)];

    Type* getObject() { return reinterpret_cast<Type*>(objectData); }
    const Type* getObject() const { return reinterpret_cast<const Type*>(objectData); }
    Extension* getExtension() { return reinterpret_cast<Extension*>(extensionData); }
    const Extension* getExtension() const { return reinterpret_cast<const Extension*>(extensionData); }

    template <class... Args>
    TypeEx(Args&&... args) 
    {
        new (objectData) Type(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        new (extensionData) Extension();
    }
    ~TypeEx() 
    {
        getObject()->~Type();
        getExtension()->~Extension();
    }
    TypeEx(const TypeEx&) = delete;
    TypeEx& operator = (const TypeEx&) = delete;
};
```

And some helper functions:

```
template <typename Type, class... Args>
Type* createObjectEx(Args&&... args)
{
   TypeEx<Type>* retVal = new TypeEx<Type>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   return retVal->getObject();
}

template <typename Type>
typename LinkExtension<Type>::Type& getObjectEx(Type* obj)
{
   static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<TypeEx<Type>>::value, "Oops");
   static_assert(offsetof(TypeEx<Type>, objectData) == 0, "Oops");
   TypeEx<Type>* retVal = static_cast<TypeEx<Type>*>((void*)obj);
    return *(retVal->getExtension());
}

template <typename Type>
const typename LinkExtension<Type>::Type& getObjectEx(const Type* obj)
{
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<TypeEx<Type>>::value, "Oops");
    static_assert(offsetof(TypeEx<Type>, objectData) == 0, "Oops");
    const TypeEx<Type>* retVal = static_cast<const TypeEx<Type>*>((const void*)obj);
    return *(retVal->getExtension());
}

template <typename Type>
void deleteObjectEx(const Type* obj)
{
    const TypeEx<Type>* objectEx = static_cast<const TypeEx<Type>*>((const void*)obj);
    delete objectEx;
}
```

And how to link extension to class:

```
class MyClass {
public:
   virtual ~MyClass() = default; 
};
struct MyClassExtension {
    int a;
    int b;
};
template <>
struct LinkExtension<MyClass> {
    using Type = MyClassExtension;  
};
```

And proof it works:

```
void printExtension(MyClass* object);
int main() {
    MyClass* object = createObjectEx<MyClass>();
    MyClassExtension& extension = getObjectEx(object);
    extension.a = 1;
    extension.b = 2;
    printExtension(object);
    deleteObjectEx(object);

    TypeEx<MyClass> objectEx;
    objectEx.getExtension()->a = 3;
    objectEx.getExtension()->b = 4;
    printExtension(objectEx.getObject());
}

void printExtension(MyClass* object)
{
    MyClassExtension& extension = getObjectEx(object);
    std::cout << extension.a << ' ' << extension.b << std::endl;
}
```

If your compiler does not support variadic templates, the solution is still possible, but requires more hand work to be complete.

Comment: I don't have access for modifying the class, it's a third party class !

Comment: @StephaneRolland what class is responsible for creating MyClass objects - is it also third party class - or it is your code?

Comment: MyClass* is a pointer to a 3rd party party class. But I am responsible for the instanciating the objects, and their scope of life.

Comment: @StephaneRolland so I made update - to solve your very case - when you  are creating objects. So you can always create objects with its possible extension (Note that your extension type could be any type - even std::unique_ptr<> of some type.

Comment: Are you allowed to cast like that? The pointer to `struct TypeEx` isn't always the same as the pointer to `object`.

Comment: @Velkan, thank for pointing this out. I make the solution more robustness - i.e. make it always standard layout type... Probably it could be left in its old form for most compilers - but just to strictly follow the C++ standard...