# Add data to an existing class without inheritance, maps or modification of the class

Tags: c++

The class could be anything (non-pod, may have virtual functions).

We can't modify the source code of the class.

- there is a control over the factory method that creates objects
- objects re allocated on the heap
- objects are not copied after creation
- it is known at compile time which classes need that additional data

Usage example:

```
void f(ThirdPartyClass *o)
{
    MyData *d = getData(o);
    ...
}
```

Possible solution is to be creating wrapper structs when constructing the objects of `ThirdPartyClass` type:

```
struct Wrapper
{
    ThirdPartyClass o;
    MyData d;
};
```

But then how to implement the `MyData* getData(ThirdPartyClass *o)` function? It's not correct to use the `offsetof` macro to get from `ThirdPartyClass*` to the `Wrapper*`. Is there a way?

Comment: There is no way in standard C++. Take the bitter pill, use the Wrapper directly in your code, pass the member to the library when required, and don't try to be clever.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? These limitations look rather arbitrary to me.

Comment: @StoryTeller, good to have a confirmation. It wasn't completely clear from other stackoverflow questions.

Comment: @yeputons, of course it is. There are organizational problems with people that don't want to see an additional pointer in their classes.

Comment: If target class has virtual methods then it is possible to attach some custom content and / or behaviors to it using vtable spoofing.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I've pinged the author of an old answer, and he came up with this placement-new version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13009718/4742108. Does it look correct?

Comment: @Velkan - Considering his code sample has an explicit static assert on `is_standard_layout<TypeEx<Type>>`, any embedding of your `ThirdPartyClass` in there will not compile.

Comment: @StoryTeller, it static asserts on the wrapper class. But the wrapper is just two byte-arrays in a struct.

Comment: @Velkan - The fact `getObjectEx` always reinterpret casts the buffer instead of storing the pointer returned by the new expression means that this code relies on type punning. Decide for yourself if you are okay with that. It's as valid as reinterpret casting the member of a structure that has no bases and no virtual functions (my original answer).

Comment: @StoryTeller, maybe the cast in `getExtension()` is sloppy, but it isn't vital (our data can be stored by pointer). The important cast relies on the equality of pointers (not sure how): 18.6.1.3 Placement-new `void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr)` returns `ptr`. And afterwards, the reinterpret cast rules that don't have any standard-layout limitations in 5.2.10: converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (alignment of T2 is no stricter of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. At least the standard-layout isn't involved.

Comment: The standard only guarantees a round trip, you'll only get the original char pointer back. Don't extrapolate from this that the standard allows you to assume anything about the pointer to T you get. If you are worried about UB in general, then you are acting way too nonchalant about it here.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a "database-oriented" procedure. Assuming you have registered your Wrappers into a vector, you could do something like :

```
std::vector<Wrapper> containers;
MyData* getData(ThirdPartyClass *o) {
 for(int i = 0; i < containers.size(); i++) {
    if(&containers[i] == o)
       return &containers[i].d;
 }
}
```

Maybe another approach would be to store `ThirdPartyClass *parent`into your `MyData`objects and you can then iterate over a vecotr of MyData.

Comment: It's a map. I've mentioned maps in the title of the question.